# Is Fraggle Rock a dimensional nexus?

Tags: magical-theory, fraggle-rock

The 1980s Jim Henson show *Fraggle Rock* introduced us to the titular creatures, Fraggles, and their home, Fraggle Rock, an immense series of underground caves that seem to access our own world at different points. The Fraggles call us humans "Silly creatures", with one in particular, the explorer "Traveling" Matt venturing out into our world (somewhere in the USA) and meeting, interacting and learning (often erroneously, due to his own flawed deductions) from humans about their/our way of life, places  and practices.

Fraggle society seems to mirror our own in many ways; they dress, have social codes, games, rituals, a whole culture of their own. The Fraggles in the USA are shown perfectly understanding and communicating in English, with the exception of some concepts and items which are exclusive to the Fraggle world (Doozers and their constructions as food, for example). Also, it should be noted that Fraggles aren't the *only* creatures living within the cave system; though the seemingly dominant populace, they share it with other species.

Where as Fraggles would be about 2 feet in height on average, and no distinct phenotype (being diverse in color, proportion and specific features), with a rather arts and oral traditions-based, Bohemian society, the aforementioned Doozers are *completely* different. As tiny (perhaps 2-4 inches high), sentient, green-skinned humanoids with a somewhat more rigid-minded, "science and architecture" focused society, Doozers dedicate themselves to continuous design, construction and inventive works. Of all the shown species, Doozers seem to have the best "Functional Social symbiotic" relationship with the Fraggles; they interact infrequently, but genially, and Doozers rely on the bigger beings to continually remove their old constructions. However, the Doozers are *far* more technologically advanced, have their own history and practices, and govern themselves, basically functioning as a pocket community within the Rock.

[image: Fraggles and Doozers singing and dancing together, for a size perspective]

There are also other non-sentient creatures, such as Poison Cacklers (giant arachnid-like cave scavengers) and other cave beasts which the Fraggles consider dangerous.

[image: a close up of a Poison Cackler as described above in a cave with its tongue out]

Then there are the Ditzies; semi-invisible, non-corporeal, but still conscious beings that also share a type of symbiosis with Fraggles, seeming to somehow feed off of the music Fraggles instinctively create. In return, the Ditzies provide light and natural energy, or "shine", throughout the caves.

[image: Fraggles celebrating their friends, the Ditzies]

*Outside* the central cave system, other beings exist as well; there are Gorgs, giant fuzzy bipeds the size of human houses who live on an isolated, but thriving farm and think themselves royalty. We only ever see one family of 3, and they view the Fraggles as pests, akin to mice.

[image: The 3 royal Gorgs stand round a table looking down at the Fraggles who are stood on it]

The Fraggles will regularly transverse the Gorgs gardens to go see "The Trash Heap", a *literal* living, thinking heap of compost that  has been around for ages. Known as Marjory, Madame Heap provides any Fraggle who comes to her with sage advice, and is always accompanied by her ... I don't know, possum, possibly.... attendants.

[image: 2 Fraggles look at the Trash Heap, a pile of trash wearing glasses with 2 rat-like creatures sat to the side of it]

And *this* is where things get confusing...

The wider, proportionately larger, somewhat alien outside world of the Gorgs and Madame Heap seem **very far removed** from the reality of "our" Earth ... but it's been *thoroughly* established that the Fraggle Rock cave system connects to *our* human world via different points; the one we most commonly see is in a New England house belonging to a human, Doc, and his dog Sprocket, accessible by a literal hole in the wall. My guess is that the house was built on top of one of the cave entrances accidentally some years before.

[image: Doc looks towards the camera standing next to the hole in the wall of the house]

Traveling Matt sends his nephew, Gobo, post cards of his adventures to Doc's address, where Gobo has to retrieve them from a trash can (*how* Matt figured out using our snail mail system while being *completely unschooled* in the ways of "outter space", I do not know... but then again, *how* he survives and *what he eats* when there's nary a Doozer building in sight in the human world is another question).

[image: A Frtaggle and a human sit in chairs opposite from each other talking]

To make things even **more** confusing, at the series end, Doc and Sprocket leave their old house and move (I believe over seas), to a new place, with another hole in the wall...and yet, *somehow,* this place *too* is connected to Fraggle Rock! By that time, Doc (who had been unaware of the Fraggles for most of the series) had met and befriended Gobo and his clique, making his leaving the house with these marvelous new little neighbors somewhat bittersweet. This new "Change of Address" was implied to be pretty far...far enough, at least, that Doc and Sprocket had to take a plane to get there....

[image: Doc and Sprocket sat on a plane with a flight attendant talking to them from the aisleway]

But he hadn't even moved into the new space for a *day* before it was shown to have a Fraggle Hole as well... and *somehow* despite the *miles* between the two locations, it was implied that, for the Fraggles at least, the new hole was within simple **walking distance** *inside* their cave system!

Now granted, magic (or at least, supernatural elements, like the Ditzies) *have* been shown to exist in the Fraggle world, to some degree; they would **have too,** for the Trash Heap to be alive *at all.* And the space Madame Heap and the Gorgs exist in would also **have** to be completely separate from our own (Gorgs never existed on *this* planet to my knowledge), yet still accessible by the Fraggles, cause it too can be gotten to via the caves.

**Is it *possible* then, that Fraggle Rock (the main cave hub itself) is some type of "Dimensional nexus" that connects various worlds from which many different beings can reach new spaces?**

It *would* explain how the disparate races all exist simultaneously within the show; the Doozers could be a technologically advanced species from another planet or time, with a colony in the Rock, and the Gorgs from some whole *other* dimension where giants exist) in a space proportional to *themselves,*) and they are roughly on Dark Age level advancement. That's why they basically "completely separated" from the modern Human world the Rock is connected to. So the cave system itself somehow "folds space," and different cave exits come out at different dimensions, in various time periods, or perhaps on completely different planets.

How else (aside from Jim Henson having one of the most rich, *blessed* imaginations in the world) can one explain *all* these places existing simultaneously, yet never interacting with each other, but all being accessible *only* to Fraggles who travel through the cave systems?

Comment: You make a very good point that Fraggle Rock may be have an extra-dimension. I don't think there is a question to answer, though,

Comment: @Ángel I think what I'm asking is if this possibility was ever hinted at or addressed in the series or its short lived cartoon spin off? I mean Doozers, Gorgs and Fraggles weren't "legendary" creatures from what I gathered...but Uncle Matt interacts with humans _daily,_ and **nobody** seems shocked or asks him "What are you?!" Also, in the _Muppet Christmas Special,_ Kermit and Robin happen upon yet _another_ Fraggle Hole in Fozzy's Moms's house, and Robin seems to know _something_ about them. Then again, this is the same reality where Frogs and Pigs produce musicals and no one flinches, so...

Comment: This question really needs a bit more research detail.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Oh? I'm sorry, Pauly; did I _miss_ something?

Comment: @Russhiro: it's just so brief!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well it is a _question,_ my man, so I'm seeking further information. I was kinda limited on what I had to go on, but then... I'm no expert. Beg pardon for the brevity.

Comment: Note, the place where the hole comes out to in our world, as well as the characters who live there and the areas that Travelling Matt explore, are localised to different regions. In the UK, for example, the hole is in a lighthouse off the Scottish coast, inhabited by a lighthouse keeper called the Captain, and Sprocket is his dog.

Comment: Is it possible that they connect to different dimensions?  My dude, it is fricken guaranteed.